# How to remove only last new line with regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a file like so:

```
const stringToTest = ' test1\n test2\n test3\n \n \n'
```

The output I want to get is:

```
stringTransformed = 'test1\n test2\n test3\n \n'
```

so in other words I want to get rid of only LAST white space and new line:

```
' \n'
```

I have tried following:

```
stringToTest.replace(/\s+\n$/, '')
```

but it removes all white spaces and new lines at the end of the file.

I know I can do it with split and join but I would prefer to do it with regular expression as it's much faster and sometimes my strings are really big so I don't want to split them into arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `\s` pattern matches any whitespace. If you subtract CR and LF symbols from it, you will only match horizontal whitespaces.

So, you may use

```
replace(/[^\S\n\r]*\n$/, '')
```

Or, to also handle CRLF endings:

```
replace(/[^\S\n\r]*\r?\n$/, '')
```

Note I changed `+` to `*` quantifier to also remove the last line break if there are no horizontal whitespace chars on the line before the last newline.

JS demo:

```js
const stringToTest = ' test1\n test2\n test3\n \n \n';
console.log(stringToTest.replace(/[^\S\n\r]*\n$/, ''));
```

Comment: Great! Indeed it does the job! Thanks